# При зажатой кнопке type='submit' отправляется подряд куча писем. Как сделать, чтобы отправлялось только одно письмо?

Tags: html, html-form, спам

Поставил google-капчу на форму, но спамеры вручную спамят: заполняют поля формы, заполняют капчу, зажимают кнопку ОТПРАВИТЬ (type='submit') и писем отправляется не одно, а сразу несколько штук. Как бороться с этим? Спасибо

Comment: Капчу вряд ли вручную вводят. Просто нужно код-во символов увеличивать в капче. 8 например

Answer (score 0):

Поставь обработчик события на onClick по submit-кнопке.
В обработчике будет два действия:
1. Блокировка этой кнопки
2. Ajax к серверу на отправку письма.

В коллбэке ajax на success и error кнопку submit обратно разблокируй. 
Помимо этого в коллбэках, выводи alert или popup с сообщением об успешной отправке письма.
Так же в коллбэках очищай свою форму через reset()
Таким образом письмо отправится единожды.

Заблокировать кнопку через jQuery:
$(“buttonID”).prop(“disables”, “true”)